# Why do I need a goroutine in order for this to work?

Tags: go

Im not 100% clear on why my code doesnt work

```
package main
 
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)
 
//var wg sync.WaitGroup
 
func main() {
 
    c := make(chan int)
    send(c)
    receive(c)
}
 
func send(c chan<- int) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
                c <- j
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
 
    wg.Wait()
    close(c)
}
 
func receive(c <-chan int) {
    for v := range c {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

If I put Go before send it works fine. But i thought having the wait in the send would mean the program would wait there until the go routines created in that function completed and would only go to the receive function once they were all done and so the channel was populated?

Comment: "i thought having the wait in the send would mean the program would wait there until the go routines created in that function completed and would only go to the receive function once they were all done" - correct, but they can't finish until something receives those values, so you have a chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: Here's a way to look at it: `send` and `receive` are run sequentially, meaning that none of the receiving begins until all of the sending is completed. The problem is now obvious, as others have pointed out, that the senders can only send while the receivers are receiving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The channel is not buffered. A write to an unbuffered channel will only complete if there is a read from that channel in another goroutine. So, all the goroutines created in the `send` are stuck waiting to write to the channel, never reaching `wg.Done`, and thus, `wg.Wait` waits indefinitely. When you put the `send` in a separate goroutine, `receive` can run, thus reading from the channel, releasing the waiting goroutines.